# Checking room availability using JTable and JCalendar throws SQL exception

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, jcalendar

The program I wrote checks for rooms available in a hotel. I used JCalendar for the user to enter the dates and JTable to display the rooms available. 
The problem is that when I click on Check Availability button, it's throwing an SQL Exception.

Here are the code snippets:

```
public class Room_Availability extends JFrame {

//Note: Didn't add codes about instantiating panels, setting layouts and all

JLabel arr_date= new JLabel("Arrival Date:");
JLabel dep_date= new JLabel("Departure Date:");
JButton chk_btn= new JButton("Check Availability");
JDateChooser arrival = new JDateChooser();
JDateChooser departure = new JDateChooser();
JTable CheckAvail= new JTable();

Room_Availability(){

chk_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           CheckAvailActionPerformed(evt);
       }
   });

  }


 private void CheckAvailActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               


   ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String connectionUser = "root";
        String connectionPassword = "admin";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser,
                connectionPassword);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String query= "select * from room as ro" +
                 "where ro.room_id not in "+
                " ("+
                   "select re.room_no"+
                  " from testing.booking as re "+
                   "where (arrival_date >= ? and departure_date < ?)"+
                     "or (departure_date >= ? and arrival_date < ?)"+
                 " )";

        PreparedStatement pStmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);

        java.util.Date utilDate = arrival.getDate();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());   

        java.util.Date utilDate1 = departure.getDate();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate1 = new java.sql.Date(utilDate1.getTime()); 

        pStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
        pStmt.setDate(2, sqlDate1);
        pStmt.setDate(3, sqlDate);
        pStmt.setDate(4, sqlDate1);


        rs = pStmt.executeQuery();

        CheckAvail.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
  }   
}
```

Here is how the GUI looks like:
[image]

When I execute the query(with the same dates as I enter on the JCalendar) on MySQL database this is what is displayed and should be displayed on the JTable:
[image]

Here are the errors I am getting:

[image]

Comment: There are 4 question marks in your query, meaning it requires 4 parameters; you only specify 2 parameters.

Comment: I commented out the line `"or (departure_date >= ? and arrival_date < ?)"+` but I am now getting `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You should set parameter for each '?' in the query. There are four '?' placeholders but You set only two of them

```
    pStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
    pStmt.setDate(2, sqlDate1);
```

It should be something like this

```
pStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
pStmt.setDate(2, sqlDate1);
pStmt.setDate(3, sqlDate1);
pStmt.setDate(4, sqlDate);
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it but it threw  `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`

Comment: @Diksha, can you edit your questiowith the code you have after the attempt to fix it based on this answer?

Comment: Note: The query should actually be like this for it to work accordingly: `pStmt.setDate(3, sqlDate);
pStmt.setDate(4, sqlDate1);`

Answer (score 1):

There is missing space in lines:

```
"where (arrival_date >= ? and departure_date < ?)"+
"select * from room as ro" +
```

Just add one space at the end of the string

```
"where (arrival_date >= ? and departure_date < ?) "+
"select * from room as ro " +
```

Comment: It still threw `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`

Comment: i edited my answer, there is another line without space, better check them all